# Quick Select in O(1) using tail recursion

Tags: recursion, quicksort, space

I was doing a ZTM course there he said that **Quick Select** algo at worst case can be O(1) Space complexity using tail recursion as it only makes one recursive calls.

His Code was

```
const quickSelect = function (nums, left, right, indexToFind) {
  const partitionIndex = getPartition(nums, left, right);

  if (partitionIndex === indexToFind) {
    return nums[partitionIndex];
  } else if (indexToFind < partitionIndex) {
    return quickSelect(nums, left, partitionIndex - 1, indexToFind);
  } else {
    return quickSelect(nums, partitionIndex + 1, right, indexToFind);
  }
};
```

And here is the optimized version of **Quick Sort** from [GFG article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-tail-call-optimization-reducing-worst-case-space-log-n/) it looks like quickSelect and one recursive call each time.
Code:

```
def quickSort(arr, low, high)
{
    while (low < high):
        ''' pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
           at right place '''
        pi = partition(arr, low, high);
 
        # If left part is smaller, then recur for left
        # part and handle right part iteratively
        if (pi - low < high - pi):
            quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
            low = pi + 1;
         
        # Else recur for right part
        else:
            quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
            high = pi - 1;
}
```

Why can't this be O(1) Space complexity then using Tail rec?

Comment: The recursive call takes up space in the stack. QuickSelect can (explicitly or implicitly) be implemented in a strictly iterative formulation - QuickSort cannot (unless you use an explicit stack), which - obviously - uses space).

Comment: No, it wasn't a iterative approach he was talking about. It was a rec approach only for quickselect.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative version of quick select using Lomuto partition scheme. I don't know if python optimization handles tail recursion.

```
def quickselect(a, k):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(a)-1
    while (lo < hi):
        p = a[hi];              # Lomuto partition
        i = lo;
        for j in range(lo, hi):
            if (a[j] < p):
                a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
                i += 1
        a[i],a[hi] = a[hi],a[i]
        if (k == i):            # if pivot == kth element, return it
            return a[k]
        if (k < i):             # loop on partition with kth element
            hi = i - 1
        else:
            lo = i + 1
    return a[k]                 # sorted to kth elemement, return it
```

Iterative version of quick select using Hoare partition scheme, it has to loop until lo == hi, since the pivot and values equal to pivot can end up anywhere after a partition step. However, it is faster than Lomuto partition  scheme (at least with Python).

```
def quickselect(a, k):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(a)-1
    while (lo < hi):
        p = a[(lo + hi) // 2]   # Hoare partition
        i = lo - 1
        j = hi + 1
        while(1):
            while(1):
                i += 1
                if(a[i] >= p):
                    break
            while(1):
                j -= 1
                if(a[j] <= p):
                    break
            if(i >= j):
                break
            a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
        if (k <= j):            # loop on partition with kth element
            hi = j
        else:
            lo = j + 1
    return a[k]                 # sorted to kth elemement, return it
```